# Jhipster update i18n language for a user

Tags: internationalization, jhipster

I have a Jhipster application and already changed the default language in the app to use french.

In **app.js**:

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr');
```

But I can't change the language that was set for a User. I am using the default User account created with the application: "user".
When I logged in the application and change the language to French and save the User information, the default User table is not changed. So when I logged in again, the language is English.

The **lang_key** field is still **en** in the table.

Do you know how to change the language for a User?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not implemented in Jhipster. So the lang_key is only set when you create a new user.
I added it to my application by doing the following:

**NOTE:** This is changing the language of the current user by setting it by the current language in use in the app.

**UserService.java**

Add the langKey to the method:

```
public void updateUserInformation(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String langKey) {
  ...
  currentUser.setLangKey(langKey);
  ...
}
```

**AccountResource.java**

In the Post Request (add the langKey by getting it from the userDTO):

```
userService.updateUserInformation(userDTO.getFirstName(), userDTO.getLastName(), userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getLangKey());
```

**settings.controller.js**

Finally in the setting controller set the language in use (just after the account is fetched)

```
$scope.settingsAccount = account;
$scope.settingsAccount.langKey = $translate.use();
```

You will need to add *$translate* to the function parameter of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want set language for each user, you can set it in liquibase, `users.csv`. And in this file find column - `"lang_key"`. and set language. For default it is "en".

I did, that always was only one language. In any roles and for any users. 
Find this block in app.js:

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: 'i18n/{lang}/{part}.json'
        });
```

and change line

```
urlTemplate: 'i18n/{lang}/{part}.json'
```

to

```
urlTemplate: 'i18n/fr/{part}.json'
```

In this case always will be french language

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am going to look into it to check if there is another way to proceed. Your solution seems to force the template to use only "fr", but I rather like to find a solution more configurable.

Comment: If you find it - please, tell me))